# How can I rotate and move a cylindrical rod from one side with respect to other side in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, physics

I have 3 questions here. If answer of 2nd question is yes, then i dont need answer for 1st question.

I want to rotate one end of this rod and when i rotate 2nd end. i want it to move parallel to 1st end. Right now when i rotate right end in upper direction, left end goes in lower direction and pivot remains at its position. When rod is in straight line, one end will simply rotate and when rod is already tilted, it will move one end in line with the other end.

Can i simple move one end of rod? instead of rotating it just simply move one end of rod upwards and not the entire rod?

when i use gravity on the ball it falls on the rod and take the rod down with it. if i make rod kinemetic, it wont move or rotate. i want ball to use gravity but not to drag rod with itself.

[image]

Comment: So, you want to rotate rod but don't want to move along with gravity when ball hits it?

Answer (score 0):

Okay: if I understand it correctly, you want to move one end of the rod up, while the other is remaining where it is, like a tennis bat?

To move only one end of the rod, while the other one remains where it is, I would suggest using a parent object.
Have a parent object (Parent_Rod), make the rod the child of the aforementioned parent.

Now, set up up, so the root of the Child_Rod, that you do not want to move is at the Parent_Rods root. So the non-using end of your rod should be at [0, 0, 0,] of the parent. Then don't rotate the rod object itself, but the parent of it. This way, the rotation will be around the transform of the parent, where one end of your rod is.

Regarding the force from collision: You should not use gravity on your rod and make the rigidbody kinematic. That way you can easily control the rotation of the parent via script, while the rod itself remains unaffected of collisions.

Hope this helps, hope I got the question correctly.